# SSH Pubkey Auth works on fast wifi, not on slow wifi

Tags: networking, server, ssh, authentication

This is a weird one. I use a small fleet of Chromebooks to do professional network testing, and I wrote some tools that use SSH with pubkey auth to run simultaneous tests.

The problem is, if the wifi connection isn't superb, the auth times out more often than not. For example, if I've got a long range 5 GHz connection which returns 100% of pings but has a median latency of 100ms or so, auth hangs after `send packet: type 50`, never receiving the packet type 51 to complete the auth.

```
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
```

Yes, `UseDNS no` is on, on both client and sender. I've also disabled all non-essential PAM modules, and disabled HostBasedAuth, RSAAuth, and GSSAPI on both client and sender.

The same two laptops in the same location will complete password auth without a problem - if a pubkey is present for the user on the client side, it'll have to time that out first before it fails through and ask for the password; but if there is no pubkey for the client user, it'll prompt for the password and accept it immediately.

If I move the server laptop closer to the router, so that the median latency falls in something more like the 50ms range, the pubkey auth works fine.

I can't find anything on the internets referring to a problem with high latency pubkey authentication on machines where pubkey auth works fine with lower latency, but here I am. Anybody got any ideas?